# Hello world for spoken NLP interaction (like Siri)?

Tags: nlp, speech-recognition, siri

If I have zero experience developing spoken NLP interaction, what is the easiest way for me to make a Hello World, and begin experimenting from there?

Any platforms and programming languages and APIs are relevant here, as long as they give me the most basic equivalent of Hello World AND are flexible enough that I could potentially play around for a few hours in that environment using various public REST APIs and glueing strings/regex together and get some useful demo apps out of it.

Please offer kind suggestions to improve this question if it's not clear enough, since it's probably a topic on a lot of programmers' minds and something which is not yet mainstream.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to play with building blocks, you can use:

- either [SphinxCMU](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) or the Google's voice recognition API (used by Chrome) to turn the user's voice into text
- the [Wit API](http://wit.ai) to extract meaning (the user intent/question) from text
- and then our own module to build an answer

Answer (score 0):

Start looking on existing projects like this one:

[Pi-Voice](https://github.com/rob-mccann/Pi-Voice)

read the code and analyze what they are doing. Those are toys anyway since technology behind Siri is quite complex

To get a deep understanding of the technology read the papers from the CALO project which was a Siri base:

[Calo Project Website](https://pal.sri.com/Plone/framework)